# How to permit Google Cloud Data Fusion to connect to an AWS RDS MySQL database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm getting an error in configuring a database connection in a Google Cloud Data Fusion Pipeline.

> "Encountered SQL error while getting query schema: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

We can't connect outside of the company building as the company IP's are whitelisted in AWS security settings. I can query easily using mysql workbench inside the company so, I'm guessing I need to add some IPs to our AWS security groups to provide Data Fusion permissions? I can't find a guideline on this. Where can I find the ip's required to provide in AWS? (Assuming that might fix it)

I've added a mysql plugin artefact using 'mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar', which is referred to by plugin name 'mysql-connector-java'.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do VPN between your GCP VPC and your AWS VPC where your RDS is residing

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-gcp-apis-from-an-external-network
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automated-network-deployment-multicloud

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

- Create Haproxy with public IP
  Data Fusion --> VM Haproxy Public IP --> AWS RDS Private IP